# How to operate the consecutive elements with some standard module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

An example:

```
l = [1, 3, 8, 10, 20]
```

Result:

```
[2, 5, 2, 10]
```

I want to get the difference between the two numbers

Some efforts I tried:

1. list-comprehension, I like this but if I want to do some nested list-comprehension, it is maybe a little hard to read:

```
print([l[i]-l[i-1] for i in range(1, len(l))])
```

2. I tried to find it in [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).I find some very similar function like [`accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)(Even `functools.reduce`).Exactly, they couldn't get expected result.

Does there has some function in the standard library could achieve that?like:

```
func(lambda x,y: x-y, l)
```

If this question is duplicate, please tell me and I will delete this post.Thanks <3.

Comment: ***If this question is duplicate, please tell me***: Read up on [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) and find it out yourself.

Comment: @stovfl Sure, I must search it on the Internet before I ask this question..But I didn't find it....

Comment: [`numpy.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html). Searching _"python difference between consecutive numbers"_ gave this as the first result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614361/finding-the-difference-between-consecutive-numbers-in-a-list-python

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Though it is not the standard module.It seems `numpy.dff` should be the only way to achieve that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `zip`:

```
l = [1, 3, 8, 10, 20]

result = [y - x for x, y in zip(l, l[1:])]
print(result)
```

Which yields

```
[2, 5, 2, 10]
```

---

`zip` binds together elements from multiple iterators in one tuple, `l[1:]` is just the slice notation for `[3, 8, 10, 20]` (starting at the second element, that is). You can see it yourself with:

```
for pair in zip(l, l[1:]):
    print(pair)
```

Which yields

```
(1, 3)
(3, 8)
(8, 10)
(10, 20)
```

---

An alternative could be:

```
from itertools import tee


def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


result = list(map(lambda tpl: tpl[1] - tpl[0], pairwise(l)))
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, +1 but does there have some function to do it directly?like `func(lambda x,y: x-y, l)`.This also do a list-comprehension.

Comment: @KevinMayo: You could wrap the functionality in a function yourself. A list comprehension is usually very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Several ways:

```py
[y - x for x, y in zip(x[:-1], x[1:])]  # [2, 5, 2, 10]

list(map(lambda xy: xy[1] - xy[0], zip(x[:-1], x[1:])))  # [2, 5, 2, 10]
```

Or a slightly more readable way if you write a couple boilerplace functions:

```py
def lag(x):
    return zip(x[:-1], x[1:])

def diff(pair):
    return pair[1] - pair[0]

list(map(diff, lag(x)))
```

Of course, in either case you should handle corner cases around list size, etc.

Comment: Thanks for answer, +1 but does there have some function to do it directly?like `the_standard_func(lambda x,y: x-y, l)`.This also do a list-comprehension.

Comment: This uses stdlib for everything, and all of the code here is extremely light weight. If you are looking for a function this specific, you're probably going to need to use Numpy or something outside of stdlib.